# trying to display elements on the same line

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

here's what I'm trying to do - I want 'Forgot your password?' to appear on the same line as 'Remember me', like in the image. I'm using the simple_form gem, and it's really messing things up - I mean, normally I'd put 'display:inline' in my 'forget your password' div , or I'd make it into a span, and it would show up ok, I'm sure, but not in this case. Thanks for any help!

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<div class='sign-in-section'>

          <%= simple_form_for(User.new, :as => :user, :url => session_path(:user), :html => {}) do |f| %>

            <div class="inputs">
    <%= f.input_field :email, :required => false, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => I18n.t('sign_in.email_address_placeholder') %>
              <br/>
              <%= f.input_field :password, :required => false,  :placeholder => I18n.t('sign_in.password_placeholder') %>
              <%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean, :label => false, :inline_label => 'Remember me' %>
              <div class='links'>
              <%= link_to I18n.t('sign_in.forgot_password'), new_user_password_path %>
              </div>
            </div>

   </br>
   <span class="actions"><%= f.button :submit, I18n.t('sign_in.sign_in_button'), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>

              <%= link_to I18n.t('sign_in.sign_up_button'), new_user_registration_path, :class => "btn btn-warning" %>

          <% end %>
        </span>

    </div>
```

And my links div css is this (maybe there's a way with simple_form I don't even need the div in there?):

```
.sign-in-section .links {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Can you do a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hm, not sure you can do a jsfiddle with rails gems? I'll look, but don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the link to float on right side.

```
.sign-in-section .links {
    display:inline;
    float: right;
}
```

If this puts the link below the Remember me, then you need to make a re-ordering of the html elements as like

```
<div class="inputs">
    <%= f.input_field :email, :required => false, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => I18n.t('sign_in.email_address_placeholder') %>
    <br/>
    <div class='links'>
        <%= link_to I18n.t('sign_in.forgot_password'), new_user_password_path %>
    </div>
    <%= f.input_field :password, :required => false,  :placeholder => I18n.t('sign_in.password_placeholder') %>
    <%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean, :label => false, :inline_label => 'Remember me' %>

</div>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, you are right float is enough as display is already made to inline. Updated the answer.

Comment: your suggestion puts it on the right, alright, but it's below right of the 'Remember Me'. working on a solution...

Comment: what is your css for the remember me?

Answer (score 1):

thanks for all your help. They put me on the right track; some answers were updated while I was working on my solution based on what you said, so cheers for the time and effort. With some of your solutions I got the 'forgot password?' on the right, ok, but it was below-right of 'Remember me'.

The solution I used was adding a new div for 'remember me', and then another div for 'Forgot password?', like so:

```
      <div class='links1'>
      <%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean, :label => false, :inline_label => 'Remember me' %>
      </div>
      <div class='links'>
      <%= link_to I18n.t('sign_in.forgot_password'), new_user_password_path %>
      </div>
```

And in my css:

```
.links1 {
  float:left;
}

.links {
  float:right;
}
```

For some reason it was throwing my 'log in' and 'sign up' buttons out of place, but I changed my `<span class>` to a `<div class>`, and it looked ok again.

So simple when you see it done!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
.sign-in-section .links,
.sign-in-section .inputs  {
    display:inline;
}

.sign-in-section .links  {
   float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a guess.

```
.sign-in-section .links {
    width: 350px;
    float: right;
}
```

You need to modify the width px.

Answer (score 0):

use `display:inline;` for remember me input too
or use `float:left;` and `float:right;`

Answer (score 0):

the `div` element which wraps the 'forgotten password' link is rendered as a block-elment. you can override this with a css property:

```
<div class='links' style='display:inline;'>
<%= link_to I18n.t('sign_in.forgot_password'), new_user_password_path %>
</div>
```

think about adding the property to a css style for class 'links' or to define another css class, eg. 'inlined'.